# Why is the circuit breaker for my furnace stuck in the off position?

Tags: electrical, repair, furnace, circuit-breaker

The breaker for my furnace is stuck in the off position. We were away for the winter and had someone shut it off, and now the breaker won't turn on at all. We shut off the thermostat upstairs thinking that may have been the problem, but it still won't go on.

Why is this happening, and how do we fix it?

Comment: Are you referring to the breaker in your main electrical box aka load center?

Comment: Did the breaker trip? If so, it will be in the middle and you will need to switch it fully off before you turn it on.

Comment: It could be the breaker won't turn on because there is a fault in your furnace or it's wiring. Your breaker may be just doing it's job and preventing you from burning your house down or electrocuting someone. If in doubt, I'd call an electrician.

Comment: By "*won't turn on*", do you mean you physically can't move the switch, the switch moves to the on position but then clicks and moves back to the off position, or the switch moves but when released springs back to the middle-ish position?

Comment: The main breaker box, the switch moves, but when released goes right back to off or middle. I did be sure to flip it off first before trying to flip on.

Comment: @Anishaa What was the resolution?

Answer (score 1):

If you physically cannot flip it either to off or on (try off first), then it's broken and needs to be replaced.

Comment: Yes, it's the breaker in the main box. I did flip to off then try flipping to on, it won't flip on at all it just goes right back to the off position. So, it moves but when released springs back to middle